implement payment in flutter with adyen
I want to use adyen payment in flutter.I found a package called adyen_checkout: ^1.1.0.but I dont know how to use it.any one have experice in what can I do and how to implement this payment in my flutter app?

Yes I have expereinced in it, i have implmented it in my flutter app, recently.
First create merchant test account on adyen dashbord, get required details.
Then call below api in the postmen, it will return session id, session data and client key, then use it in your flutter app, it will open adyen payment modale.
Curl call on posment but you will need to implement below api in the backend.
    curl --location 'https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v70/sessions' \
--header 'x-api-key: your api key' \
--header 'Idempotencykey: your clientKey' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "merchantAccount": "MerchantAccountName",
  "amount": {
      "value": 10,
      "currency": "EUR"
  },
  "returnUrl": "my-app://adyen",
  "reference": "oder1",
  "countryCode": "NL",
  "recurringProcessingModel": "CardOnFile"
}'

adyen doc link:
You can use two appraoched drop in approach and component appraoch.
Component approach code:
`Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
      appBar: const DefaultAppBar(
        titleText: 'Add New Card',
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              // Note text
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0, left: 5, right: 5),
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'Note ',
                        style:
                            TextStyles.blackNormalBold.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                      const TextSpan(
                          text:
                              'In order to verify your account we may charge your account with a small amount that will be refunded.',
                          style: TextStyles.greySmallRegular),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              /// Card Component wrapped in FutureBuilder
              FutureBuilder<SessionCheckout>(
                future: PaymentUtils.createSession(
                    cardComponentConfiguration, sessionId, sessionData,),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }

                  final sessionCheckout = snapshot.data!;

                  final paymentMethod = PaymentUtils.extractPaymentMethod(
                      sessionCheckout.paymentMethods,);

                  return AdyenCardComponent(
                    configuration: cardComponentConfiguration,
                    paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
                    checkout: sessionCheckout,
                    onPaymentResult: (paymentResult) async {
                      var title;
                      switch (paymentResult) {
                        case PaymentAdvancedFinished():
                          title = 'Finished';
                        case PaymentSessionFinished():
                          showCustomToast(
                            type: ToastType.SUCCESS,
                            title: 'Finished',
                            subtitle: paymentResult.resultCode.name,
                          );

                        case PaymentCancelledByUser():
                          showCustomToast(
                            type: ToastType.ERROR,
                            title: 'Cancelled by user',
                            subtitle: 'Cancelled by user',
                          );
                        case PaymentError():
                          showCustomToast(
                            type: ToastType.ERROR,
                            title: 'Error occurred',
                            subtitle: paymentResult.reason.toString(),
                          );
                      }
                      // Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );`

Drop in arpproach:
final dropInConfiguration = DropInConfiguration(
    countryCode: countryCode,
    environment: Environment.test,
     clientKey: state.paymentResponse?.payload?.clientKey ?? '',
   );
  
   final sessionCheckout = await AdyenCheckout.session.create(
     sessionId: state.paymentResponse?.requestId ?? '',
     sessionData: state.paymentResponse?.payload?.sessionData ?? '',
     configuration: dropInConfiguration,
   );
 
   final paymentResult = await AdyenCheckout.session.startDropIn(
     dropInConfiguration: dropInConfiguration,
     checkout: sessionCheckout,
   );
 
   debugPrint('paymentResult: $paymentResult');


in drop in it needs country code.what did you about it? @Sohail Anwar

Please pass harded coded country code like 'PK',
And you can get dynamically country code from 'ip address'
by using this endpoint   https://api.ipify.org?format=json and, 'https://ipinfo.io/$ip/json?token=$apiToken'.

thank you so much @Sohail Anwar
